# Tomar datos de una api y mostrarla en html con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, api

Estuve tratando de probar la integración en `javascript` de una `api`.Y mostrar los nombres de los personajes en html, del cual es un array de objetos.

Pero cuando hago :

```
$.get("http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/api/characters ",function(valores,status){
     
      console.log(status)
      console.log(valores)
      
      
     for (name of valores){
       console.log(valores.name)
     }
})
```

Me devuelve error `UNDEFINED`. Quiero captar el valor para luego mostrarlo en html con `document.write o inner html`

Comment: Por favor, puedes actualizar tu pregunta añadiendo el mensaje de error que te genera?

Answer (score 3):

Estás solicitando al servidor un `JSON`, no código `XML`, por tanto, no utilices `$.get`. Usa `$.getJSON`.

```js
$.getJSON( "http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/api/characters", function( valores,status ) {
  console.log(status)
  console.log(valores)
    
 for (personaje of valores){
   console.log(personaje.name)
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```